# HTML5 circle and arrow with gradient background

Tags: html, canvas

I need a function in HTML5 that with given context, x1, y1, x2, y2 would draw me a circle (at beginning of this vector) with arrow that represents the vector itself, that would have gradient background. Left image is what I got - I am not pleased with the result... right image is visualisation of what I would like to make.

[image]

Could anybody help me with that please?

This is my arrow function (circle is obvious):

```
function arrow(context, fromx, fromy, tox, toy){
    var headlen = 10;
    var angle = Math.atan2(toy-fromy,tox-fromx);
    context.moveTo(fromx, fromy);
    context.lineTo(tox, toy);
    context.lineTo(tox-headlen*Math.cos(angle-Math.PI/6),toy-headlen*Math.sin(angle-Math.PI/6));
    context.moveTo(tox, toy);
    context.lineTo(tox-headlen*Math.cos(angle+Math.PI/6),toy-headlen*Math.sin(angle+Math.PI/6));
}
```

Comment: Yes... everyone `-1` without a word. Great.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I'll bite...

If your arrow function is working fine now, you can also draw a circle in that function.

This modified arrow() will draw both the circle and arrow in gray.

Since you want to change the context state ( change fill/stroke to gray ) you should wrap the path drawing commands in context.save and context.restore.

You should (must!) begin all atomic path drawings with context.beginPath.  This prevents path drawings from being inadvertently repeated.

This refactoring of your arrow uses context transforms to set the rotation point at x1,y1 and then draws the circle and then draws the arrow to x2,y2.

A Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/87T8d/

[image]

Example arrow function:

```
function arrow(x1,y1,x2,y2){
    var dx=x2-x1;
    var dy=y2-y1;
    var radians=Math.atan2(dy,dx);
    var length=Math.sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy);
    // save the unrotated context state
    ctx.save();
    // set the rotation point as x1,y1
    ctx.translate(x1,y1);
    // rotate the canvas by the angle of the vector
    ctx.rotate(radians);
    // draw the circle
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(0,0,8,0,Math.PI*2);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillStyle="gray";  // or gradient if you prefer
    ctx.fill();
    // draw the arrow
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(0,0);
    ctx.lineTo(length,0);
    ctx.lineTo(length-7,-4);
    ctx.lineTo(length-7,4);
    ctx.lineTo(length,0);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillStyle="gray";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.strokeStyle="gray";
    ctx.stroke();
    // restore the context to its unrotated state
    ctx.restore();
}
```

Comment: Ok and what about gradient on whole "object"?

Comment: Actually, I don't see a gradient on your illustration and a gradient would visually break your circle-arrow object apart to the viewer.  But if you want a gradient, then add a gradient.  Define the gradient line from fromx/fromy to tox/toy.  Define color stops with addColorStop(percent,color). And make the gradient fill active with context.fillStyle=gradient.  Cheers!

Comment: Grey arrows (right image) are gradiented. Not sure what you mean by breaking circle-arrow object apart to the viewer.

Comment: Ok, then apply your gradient.  That's your design decision rather than a coding issue.  Good luck with your project!

Comment: Thank you, but... my arrow function is not that good... I would rather like arrow heads to look like on right image... and have no clue how...

Comment: See my revised answer for an arrow more like your illustration.

Comment: Looks really good, but I would need linewidth = 2... and then it doesn't look perfect :/

Comment: I got you 97% of the way there...Jump-in, and do the small adjustment to my code to make it perfect.  Think of it as a way to learn what my code is doing! ;-)

Comment: I think you don't understand my problem... Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/hp35Q/ arrowhead is... not good.

Comment: Come on!!! Work with me here...what does "not good" mean.  Have you tried altering the code to get the effect you want???

Comment: markE: Oh ok... after getting some sleep I understand how it works... just added rect on top of line with length -2 ... but anyway... is it possible to fill it with gradient after rotation? Because now, depeding on vector direction, gradient rotates with it... anyway, this is great idea with that transformation... if it would be possible to apply a gradient and alpha after that, would be perfect, still `+1` for idea and afford.

Comment: Here's another design with gradient circle and tapering arrow:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/4yMW7/  Feel free to alter this design as you need.  Cheers!

Comment: So change it according to your needs!